# Is it appropriate/a good idea to use event listeners on object properties?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm creating an HTML5 Canvas Snake game with Javascript, and in trying to make my code more object-oriented, I came across a situation where I wasn't sure if what I was doing was valid.

```
Game.prototype.gameOver = function() {
    game.isOver = true;
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    console.log("Game Over!");
    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        if (e.code === "Space") {
            game.reset();
        }
    })
}
```

game.gameOver() gets called when the snake collides with the walls or itself.

Is it better to just add the reset eventListener at the global scope level and check if the game is over, or is this perfectly fine?

Edit: I realized just after posting this that a new event listener was getting added each time gameOver was called, and that was the source of my issues. I've since fixed the code so that there is never more than once instance of the event listener at once.

Comment: This is not common but not a wrong practice. addEventListener is for adding an event whenever and wherever you like.

Comment: Would be better to have a key handler interface that does nothing but set the key's state and then build your logic from that. Here the day you'll want to add an other way to restart the game (mobile?), you'll have to change that part too, when it should not be part of the changes.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you *remove that listener again* after it kicks in, this should be fine, with the only tricky bit being that you can only remove a listener if you remove it in *exactly* the same way you added it.

Using modern JS class syntax here instead of the legacy prototype syntax:

```
class Game {
  constructor(...args) {
    // ...
    this.reset();
  }

  reset() {
    this.isOver = false;
    
    // ...

    // If reset() triggered from a window keydown event, remove
    // that keydown listener so it will only kick in once:

    if (this.resetHandler) {
      window.removeEventListener(`keydown`, this.resetHandler);
      this.resetHandler = false;
    }
  }

  gameOver() {
    this.isOver = true;
    console.log(`Game Over!`);

    // Create a function that can handle a keydown event
    // and calls reset() if it's the right key, and bind
    // it so we can remove it later:

    this.resetHandler = (evt) => {
      if (evt.code === `Space`) {
        this.reset();
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener(`keydown`, this.resetHandler);

    console.log(`Press "space" on the page to continue...`);
  }
}
```

Note that arrow function, which makes sure that `this` gets preserved to what it was at declare time (i.e. the `game` instance this function's running for), rather than `function(evt) { ... }` in which `this` will be whatever the scope is at runtime (which for event listeners will be global scope, i.e. `window`).

Comment: Would be better to remove the listener in the reset method, here if something else calls reset your handler will stay and when the user press the space key the game will restart for no reason.